# Run a bash function that takes two files names as variables from command line

Tags: bash, function

I'm running an Abaqus job in Ubuntu command line using two files (`file1.inp` and `file2.f`) as follows:

```
abaqus job=file1 user=file2.f
```

Since I'm doing this a lot with different files, I wanted to make it easier as:

```
myfunc file1 file2.f
```

where `myfunc` is a `bash` function that takes the files names and run `abaqus` command `abaqus job=file1 user=file2.f`.

I appreciate any assistance to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
myfunc () {
   abaqus job="$1" user="$2"
}
```

This calls `abacus` with arguments constructed from the two arguments given to the function.

With a bit of error checking (making sure that the correct number of arguments is passed):

```sh
myfunc () {
   if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
       printf '%s: Expecting 2 arguments, got %s\n' "${FUNCNAME[0]}" "$#" >&2
       return 1
   fi

   abaqus job="$1" user="$2"
}
```

You could even give your function the name `abaqus`, but then you will have to make sure that you call the *actual* `abacus` command with

```
command abaqus job="$1" user="$2"
```

inside the function so that you don't get an infinite recursion.